# Run migration with data update after model code changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I have a model called `Restream::Custom` and an attribute `url` in it. Then I wanted to split an `url` attribute in two: `server_url` and `key`, and make both required.
I wrote such migration for this:

```
def up
    add_column :restream_customs, :key, :string

    Restream::Custom.find_each do |r|
      last_slash = r.url.rindex("/")
      r.key = r.url[last_slash + 1 .. -1] #everything after last slash
      r.url = r.url[0 .. last_slash - 1] #everything before last slash
      r.save!
        end

    change_column :restream_customs, :key, :string, null: false
    rename_column :restream_customs, :url, :server_url
end
```

And that worked fine on development. After that, I made a lot of changes in my `restream/custom.rb` in order to work with `server_url` and validate it.
And this migration consequentially failed on staging (and will fail on production) because when running `r.save!`, it faces with `validates :server_url,  presence: true` and throws `unknown attribute 'server_url' for Restream::Custom`.

What can I do to make this changes properly? In one turn, if it possible. (Do not pull from repo several times).

Answer (score 0):

try rename column `url` to `server_url` before update data

```
def up
  add_column :restream_customs, :key, :string
  rename_column :restream_customs, :url, :server_url

  Restream::Custom.find_each do |r|
    last_slash = r.server_url.rindex("/")
    r.key = r.server_url[last_slash + 1 .. -1] #everything after last slash
    r.server_url = r.server_url[0 .. last_slash - 1] #everything before last slash
    r.save!
  end

  change_column :restream_customs, :key, :string, null: false
end
```

Comment: That's... Obviously great! Thanx! But there still left one problem: I also have a `validates :key,         presence: true` in my `custom.rb` that will raise the same error :(

Comment: seem that some urls doesn't contain `key`